# How to Generate a sequence of hierarchial decimal numbers like this: 1.1, 1.2, 1.3...1.10 and so forth in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I tried this:

Create table Example

```
(
Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
ReferenceNumber float identity(1.1, 0.1)
)
GO
```

Needless to say, that didn't work. (sigh...)

and then I went on and tried to do this instead:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ReferenceNumber 
    START WITH 1.1
    INCREMENT BY 0.1;

GO
```

Create table Example

```
(
Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
ReferenceNumber float DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR ReferenceNumber
)
GO
```

I searched the internet for solutions to similar questions to mine. I had no luck. I'm not very knowledgeable and skilled in writing statements. Please help me.

Comment: any max on the minor numbering ? How do you going to use this numbering ?

Comment: I'm creating a wizard. I've divided it into 5 sections. The first view will only have automatic entries into the column of sequence 1.1, 1.2, 1.3.. so forth infinately. The second view will only have entries of 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.. and the third view will have entries into the referenceNumber column of sequence, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3.

Comment: I decided that would use a scalar function and get back the top 1 value of the Reference Number in descending order and increment it by 0.1. As well as place a "where" clause to filter for the section applicable. It should work. If you have a better solution, please feel free to share it.